# in Dart Flutter How to create Model Class for empty list value receiving in JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving the following JSON value from backend over API, how to create its Data Model Class

```
   {
     "accessories": {
        "cameras": [],
        "obds": [],
        "screens": []
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just get your complete json and paste it at https://app.quicktype.io You can generate model classes for most popular languages using it. Just make sure the json has valid data instead of empty arrays or objects.

Comment: You might consider adopting the built_value package: https://pub.dev/packages/built_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse this JSON data, do

final model = modelFromMap(jsonString);

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Model {
    Model({
        this.accessories,
    });

    Accessories accessories;

    factory Model.fromJson(String str) => Model.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Model(
        accessories: Accessories.fromMap(json["accessories"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "accessories": accessories.toMap(),
    };
}

class Accessories {
    Accessories({
        this.cameras,
        this.obds,
        this.screens,
    });

    List<dynamic> cameras;
    List<dynamic> obds;
    List<dynamic> screens;

    factory Accessories.fromJson(String str) => Accessories.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Accessories.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Accessories(
        cameras: List<dynamic>.from(json["cameras"].map((x) => x)),
        obds: List<dynamic>.from(json["obds"].map((x) => x)),
        screens: List<dynamic>.from(json["screens"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "cameras": List<dynamic>.from(cameras.map((x) => x)),
        "obds": List<dynamic>.from(obds.map((x) => x)),
        "screens": List<dynamic>.from(screens.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

Comment: are cameras, obds, and screens an array of strings? The given JSON is not complete.